# Add class to last item in Wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress

I'm making my own template for Wordpress. And I need to add class to last menu item only.
This menu looks like this:

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
  <li class="nav-item ps-4"><a class="nav-link p-0" href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item ps-4"><a class="nav-link p-0" href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item ps-4 ms-lg-4"><a class="nav-link p-0" href="#">EN</a></li>
</ul>
```

First of all I changed standard WP menu classes for my own classes.

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'change_menu_item_css_classes', 10, 4 );
function change_menu_item_css_classes( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location === 'top') {
        $classes = [ 'nav-item ps-4' ];
    } else {
        $classes = [];
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

And then I added class to last item.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_additional_class_on_lng_li', 100, 3 );
function add_additional_class_on_lng_li( $items ) {
    if ( ! empty( $items ) ) {
        $items[ count( $items ) ]->classes[] = 'ms-lg-4';
     }
     return $items;
}
```

But it wasn't added. I think it's because "wp_nav_menu_objects" always executes first and then applied "nav_menu_css_class". Could you please help me find another way to add class to last item.
Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I make a step forward with solution.
I use only one `nav_menu_css_class` filter. And test code like this.

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'change_menu_item_css_classes', 10, 4 );
function change_menu_item_css_classes( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location === 'top' && $item->menu_order == $args->menu->count ) {
        $classes = [ 'nav-item ps-4 ms-lg-4' ];
    } else {
        $classes = [];
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

And it's add class to only last menu item.
But when I use this code.

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'change_menu_item_css_classes', 10, 4 );
function change_menu_item_css_classes( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location === 'top') {
        $classes = [ 'nav-item ps-4' ];
    } elseif ( $args->theme_location === 'top' && $item->menu_order == $args->menu->count ) {
        $classes = [ 'nav-item ps-4 ms-lg-4' ];
    } else {
        $classes = [];
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

It's doesn't add class to last menu item. Seems just worked only "if" and "else", but not "elseif".

Comment: Why don't you add the class in the admin area? You don't need code for this. Go to Appearance > Menus, toggle the last menu item open and add the class there. If you don't see a box for "CSS Classes", click on Screen Options and check the box under the **Show advanced menu properties** section for CSS Classes.

Comment: Also, your `wp_nav_menu_objects` function will fail because in the filter you are saying `3` arguments will be passed to your function, but you are only passing one - `$items` **and** `wp_nav_menu_objects` only accepts `2` arguments - the items and an array of `args`. So change the `3` to a `1` or, change it to `2` and add `$args` to your `add_additional_class_on_lng_li($items, $args)`

Comment: @disinfor I know about "CSS Classes" in Wordpress admin. But this last item generated by Polylang plugin and there no fields to add custom class name.
I changed number of arguments. Still not working. When I delete 'nav_menu_css_class' then 'wp_nav_menu_objects' works. I still think, that 'wp_nav_menu_objects' executes first, because it change menu items before HTML generation. And then executes 'nav_menu_css_class' that change all classes that generated at 'wp_nav_menu_objects'. But I don't see another solution to replace standard WP menu classes and add class to last item.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Also, it's hard to know how much someone knows about WP, that's why I mentioned the CSS Classes box. On a side note, you could probably avoid adding the class if the Polylang link is always the last in the menu (if it's added dynamically) - and use CSS to target `:last-of-type` on the `li` element, although I totally get wanting to add a specific class. Good luck!

Comment: @disinfor I used similar CSS for some styles for Polylang. But classes that I need to apply to menu item are from Bootstrap. So CSS not suitable for this purpose.

Comment: You could extend Bootstrap classes in your CSS - you don't necessarily have to use the class on the element. Either way, you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found solution.
From my UPDATE part code I swapped "if" and "elseif" and this code worked for me.

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'change_menu_item_css_classes', 10, 4 );
function change_menu_item_css_classes( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location === 'top' && $item->menu_order == $args->menu->count ) {
        $classes = [ 'nav-item ps-4 ms-lg-4' ];
    } elseif ( $args->theme_location === 'top' ) {
        $classes = [ 'nav-item ps-4' ];
    } else {
        $classes = [];
    }
    return $classes;
}
```